# ¿Mapeo con mapstruct condicional dependiendo de un parámetro?

Tags: java, spring

Estoy utilizando mapstruct y me encuentro con la siguiente cuestión:

Tengo este jpa:

```
public class CandidateRecommendationJpa extends AuditingEntityJpa {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "ID_CANDIDATO_RECOMENDACION", nullable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CANDIDATO_EMISOR", nullable = false)
  private CandidateJpa candidateSender;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CANDIDATO_RECEPTOR", nullable = false)
  private CandidateJpa candidateReceiver;
}
```

Y tengo que mapearlo con la siguiente entidad:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class CandidateRecommendation {

  private Integer id;   

  private Candidate candidate;

}
```

El mapper es el siguiente:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface CandidateRecommendationJpaMapper {

  CandidateRecommendationJpaMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(CandidateRecommendationJpaMapper.class);

  @Mapping(target = "candidate.id", source = "candidateSender.id")
  @Mapping(target = "candidate.name", source = "candidateSender.name")
  @Mapping(target = "candidate.login", source = "candidateSender.employee.login")
  CandidateRecommendation toModel(CandidateRecommendationJpa jpa);

  List<CandidateRecommendation> toModels(List<CandidateRecommendationJpa> jpa);

}
```

**Problema**

En el mapper hay que especificar el atributo del jpa el cual quiero mapear, en el caso de arriba sólo mapeo con candidateSender, pero, en el caso que lo quiera hacer con candidateReceiver, ¿cómo se haría?

```
  @Mapping(target = "candidate.id", source = "candidateReceiver.id")
  @Mapping(target = "candidate.name", source = "candidateReceiver.name")
  @Mapping(target = "candidate.login", source = "candidateReceiver.employee.login")
  CandidateRecommendation toSenderModel(CandidateRecommendationJpa jpa);

  List<CandidateRecommendation> toSenderModels(List<CandidateRecommendationJpa> jpa);
```

Si intento crear el método de interfaz para especificar el otro atributo me encuentro con el siguiente error:

```
Ambiguous mapping methods found for mapping collection element to CandidateRecommendation: CandidateRecommendation toModel(CandidateRecommendationJpa jpa), CandidateRecommendation toSenderModel(CandidateRecommendationJpa jpa)
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes crearlo en una nueva interface ya que ambos se estan considerando como metodos de mapeo, entonces has lo siguiente por ejemplo:

```
  @Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
  public interface OtraInterfazMapper {
    
    
  @Mapping(target = "candidate.id", source = "candidateReceiver.id")
  @Mapping(target = "candidate.name", source = "candidateReceiver.name")
  @Mapping(target = "candidate.login", source = "candidateReceiver.employee.login")
  CandidateRecommendation toSenderModel(CandidateRecommendationJpa jpa);

  List<CandidateRecommendation> toSenderModels(List<CandidateRecommendationJpa> jpa);
    
    }
```